# React router - Allow basename with extension

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm wondering how to allow a `basename` with an .html extension to get matched by the React Router:

```
//www.domain.com/foo/bar/index.html
//www.domain.com/baz/quux.html
```

Right now, I get the error `Cannot GET /foo/bar/index.html`.

The reason I ask is we are migrating an old, static HTML/PHP site to React, and all the links on the old site end with `index.html` or `something_else.html`, and I'd like to build a mechanism to redirect visitors to the respective page on the new React web application without that error.

As it is now, any incoming traffic using a URL with a basename extension would get that error page. Without the basename, it works as expected, of course.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In production, this can be as simple as using Apache rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

However, this does not work while using the webpack development server.